# Find $\vec{r}$ which satisfies given conditions

Tags: vectors

Let $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ are three non-coplanar vectors and $\vec{r}$ be any vector in space such that $$\vec{r}.\vec{a}=1$$ $$\vec{r}.\vec{b}=2$$ $$\vec{r}.\vec{c}=3$$
and $$[\vec{a}\hspace{0.2cm} \vec{b}\hspace{0.2cm} \vec{c}]=1$$

Then find $\vec{r}$.

Problem is that using conventional method, too many variables are introduced. How should I proceed?

Comment: What vector space are you working in?  $\mathbb{R}^3$?  What does the notation $[\overrightarrow{a}\overrightarrow{b}\overrightarrow{c}]$ mean?  The triple scalar product $\overrightarrow{a}\cdot (\overrightarrow{b}\times \overrightarrow{c})$?

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes to both your questions.

Answer (score 3):

$$  \vec{b} \times \vec{c} + 2 \, \vec{c} \times \vec{a} + 3 \,  \vec{a} \times \vec{b} $$

It should be pretty easy to check that this satisfies the requested conditions.

Comment: Why did this receive a down vote??  +1

Comment: Could you give just a bit of explanation?